WPF window Doesn't acquire keyboard inputs when created from VSTO Add-in
I have an Excel add-in that displays a WPF window on the startup
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetOfficeVersion();
        
        Application.WorkbookOpen += Application_WorkbookOpen;
        Application.WorkbookAfterSave += Application_WorkbookAfterSave;
        
        
        
        TestInputsUI.Instance.Show();
    }

Nothing special about the code the TestInputsUI.Instance.Show(); is my wpf window
the problem is when I open a workbook and try to type inside the wpf textbox it sends my input to the active cell instead of the 'textBox'
this can be simply avoided by showing the wpf as Dialog but that will freeze all interactions with the Excel app until the dialog is closed.
I tried to force the focus to the textbox and even do it in a timed loop, but nothing works

Is this window that you're opening up something that always needs to be open in the background or on another monitor? If so does it need focus as soon as the excel workbook is done opening?
After the show you might try .Activate();

@Byrd I need to switch back and forth between excel and the window, tried to force focus force active(); and for test, I changed the textbox color color based on the focus state the color indicates that it is focused but the text typed goes to the active cell

The issue can be solved by spawning a new thread that will take care of showing your window and processing inputs:
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowModelessWindow();
    }

    private static void ShowModelessWindow()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var wpfWindow = new MainWindow();
            wpfWindow.Show();
            wpfWindow.Closed += (s, _) => wpfWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

            Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }

I have prepared a simple demo.
The solution is described in this answer and originates in this blog.

Thanks for the demo, the solution works but in my case, I lose some options applying it, as I need the wpf and the Excel to communicate repeatedly not just for text input but also in positioning ( the wpf must always be in the center of the excel app even if the user moved it, it must also be topmost for excel only.
